# Kafka-Consumer issue, showing some time out error

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm new to this Apache Kafka topic and I was writing some basic producer-consumer code, and I'm facing some issues with consumer code, after starting the zookeeper and Kafka, I created a topic name "firsttopic", and I'm entering some events using CLI commands as a producer and to retrieve those events as a consumer I've written a go code using Kafka-go that I'm attaching below and the error that I'm facing too. For Kafka I'm using "github.com/segmentio/kafka-go".

```
func Startkafka() {
    conf := kafka.ReaderConfig{
        Brokers:  []string{"localhost:9092"},
        Topic:    "firsttopic",
        GroupID:  "g1",
        MaxBytes: 10,
    }
    reader := kafka.NewReader(conf)
    for {
        m, err := reader.ReadMessage((context.Background()))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Some error occured", err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println("Message is : ", string(m.Value))
    }}

func main() {
    go Startkafka()
    fmt.Println("Kafka has been started...")
}
```

Error:
Kafka has been started...
Some error occured read tcp 127.0.0.1:34858->127.0.1.1:9092: i/o timeout

Comment: can you please add server.properties file and etc/hosts file

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, you should remove 127.0.1.1 from /etc/hosts mapping to localhost as it ought to remain as 127.0.0.1 during the client connection to localhost

Alternatively, connect to 127.0.0.1:9092 instead

Comment: I have done the exact same as you suggested but still, it is not working although it is not showing me any error it is not responding to any events that I'm logging through producer using the CLI command "**bin/kafka-console-producer.s--topic firsttopic --broker-list 127.0.0.1:9092**".

Comment: And what if you use `kafka-console-consumer --from-beginning`?

Comment: Or, does changing the group ID do anything differently?

Comment: on kafka-console-consumer it is showing everything that I have entered through kafka-consumer-producer.

Answer (score 0):

MaxBytes: 10 is very low, You should increase that as that may be causing an issue. The rest of the code seems to be correct. you should first try connecting using Kafka-consumer shipped with Kafka installation whether it is up which will also verify the connection string that you are using.

Comment: I have tried changing the MaxBytes size but still, nothing happened, and yes kafka-consumer is responding to the kafka-producer CLI command.

Answer (score 0):

In you main function, that `StartKafka()` calling in a `go routine`. Then it is start in another stack and run concurrently while main routine end the execution.

Remove that `go routine` and run the application. it will blocking the application and consume from Kafka topic.

If you need to build proper graceful shutdown process for the application, you have to use channels or something. But following code simply works for consume the topic content.

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("starting kafka...")
    Startkafka()
}
```